# RAD/Eclipse Configure JPA entities failing

Tags: eclipse, jsf, jpa, portlet, rad

Previously running portlet throwing error when 'Configure JPA Entities...' (have used this functionality yesterday successfully).  Message as follows

```
org.eclipse.core.runtime.CoreException: org/eclipse/jpt/ui/internal/utility/SynchronousUiCommandExecutor
    at org.eclipse.wst.common.frameworks.internal.datamodel.ui.DataModelWizard.performFinish(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.jface.wizard.WizardDialog.finishPressed(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.jface.wizard.WizardDialog.buttonPressed(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.jface.dialogs.Dialog$2.widgetSelected(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.TypedListener.handleEvent(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.runEventLoop(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.open(Unknown Source)
    at com.ibm.jee.jpa.entity.config.internal.launcher.AbstractDialogLauncher.launch(Unknown Source)
    at com.ibm.jee.jpa.entity.config.internal.launcher.AbstractEntityConfigWizardLauncher.launch(Unknown Source)
    at com.ibm.jee.jpa.entity.config.internal.action.EntityConfigAction.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.PluginAction.runWithEvent(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem.handleWidgetSelection(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem.access$2(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem$5.handleEvent(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.runEventLoop(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.runUI(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.access$4(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$7.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Unknown Source)
Contains: org/eclipse/jpt/ui/internal/utility/SynchronousUiCommandExecutor
Contains: org/eclipse/jpt/ui/internal/utility/SynchronousUiCommandExecutor
Contains: org/eclipse/jpt/ui/internal/utility/SynchronousUiCommandExecutor
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/eclipse/jpt/ui/internal/utility/SynchronousUiCommandExecutor
    at com.ibm.jee.jpa.entity.config.internal.codegen.EntityConfigCodeGenOperation.run(Unknown Source)
    at com.ibm.jee.jpa.entity.config.internal.wizard.entityconfig.operation.JpaEntityConfigWizardDelegateOperation.execute(Unknown Source)
    at com.ibm.jee.jpa.entity.config.internal.wizard.entityconfig.operation.JpaBaseWizardOperation$WizardWorkspaceBatchOperation.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.BatchOperation.executeOperation(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.JavaModelOperation.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Workspace.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.core.JavaCore.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.core.JavaCore.run(Unknown Source)
    at com.ibm.jee.jpa.entity.config.internal.wizard.entityconfig.operation.JpaBaseWizardOperation$WizardWorkspaceBatchJob.run(Unknown Source)
    at com.ibm.jee.jpa.entity.config.internal.wizard.entityconfig.operation.JpaBaseWizardOperation.execute(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.wst.common.frameworks.internal.datamodel.DataModelPausibleOperationImpl$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Workspace.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.wst.common.frameworks.internal.datamodel.DataModelPausibleOperationImpl.runOperation(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.wst.common.frameworks.internal.datamodel.DataModelPausibleOperationImpl.runOperation(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.wst.common.frameworks.internal.datamodel.DataModelPausibleOperationImpl.doExecute(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.wst.common.frameworks.internal.datamodel.DataModelPausibleOperationImpl.executeImpl(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.wst.common.frameworks.internal.datamodel.DataModelPausibleOperationImpl.cacheThreadAndContinue(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.wst.common.frameworks.internal.datamodel.DataModelPausibleOperationImpl.execute(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.wst.common.frameworks.internal.datamodel.ui.DataModelWizard$1CatchThrowableRunnableWithProgress.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.jface.operation.ModalContext$ModalContextThread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Some context - portlet application developed in RAD as a learning demo of JPA, basic JSF functionality.  Using RAD 8.5, JSF 2.0 and primefaces.  Most recent change was to import primefaces functionality and linking to this for jsf components.  JPA connection should still be working as webpage is still fetching data (after restarting, so shouldnt be cached).

Any ideas..

Comment: This looks like some sort of configuration problem. The missing class, SynchronousUiCommandExecutor, is a Dali class. Dali is a part of the Eclipse Java EE package, which I believe RAD is built on top of. For some reason Dali does not seem to be present in your configuration. Just some information that might help you solve your problem.

Comment: It does appear to be classpath related.  But I haven't removed anything from this (perhaps bringing in primefaces may have upgraded/imported a diff version of it).  Atm I think it is able to create entitymanagerqueries in a hardcoded sort of way - so I guess the Dali is being used to generate code (which I could write in the EMF class and Es)